# How to select 50 inputs and add a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 50 input elements, only numbers are allowed:

```js
function number_format_input(s) {
    var tmp;
    tmp = parseFloat(jQuery(s).val());
    if (tmp) {
        jQuery(s).val(tmp.toFixed(0));
    } else {
        jQuery(s).val("0");
    }
}

jQuery("#m15710").blur(function () { number_format_input("#m15710"); });
/* ... 50x... */
jQuery("#m20390").blur(function () { number_format_input("#m20390"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="edit_plan" type="text" id="m15710" name="data[15710][menge]" value="0">
<!-- ... 50x ... -->
<input class="edit_plan" type="text" id="m20390" name="data[20390][menge]" value="0">
```

Is possible to avaid writing 50 times

```
jQuery("#xxx").blur( function(){ number_format_input("#xxx"); } );
```

Comment: Can probably simplify `number_format_input()` also if you show that code. Suspect you are searching dom again inside it for element you already have direct access to in the event handler

Comment: `jQuery(".edit_plan").blur(number_format_input);` and then change your function like this: `var tmp = parseFloat( jQuery(this).val() );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.edit_plan` class instead of `id` like following.

```js
function number_format_input(s) {
    var tmp;
    tmp = parseFloat(jQuery(s).val());
    if (tmp) {
        jQuery(s).val(tmp.toFixed(0));
    } else {
        jQuery(s).val("0");
    }
}
    
jQuery(".edit_plan").blur(function () {
    number_format_input(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="edit_plan" type="text" id="m15710" name="data[15710][menge]" value="0">
<input class="edit_plan" type="text" id="m20390" name="data[20390][menge]" value="0">
```